# changing color of div -- using ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of div using its ID .
String is working but Hex value is not working.

Working :--

```
var div = document.getElementById('1');
div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Not working :--

```
var div = document.getElementById('1');
div.style.backgroundColor = #3e4046;
div.style.backgroundColor = 0x3e4046;
```

How to change colour of div using hex value ?

Comment: in this situations if you use **Console**  (F12) you would not end up asking this Q on SO! :) use it!

Comment: Recommend against using numbers as IDs.

Comment: @torazaburo While I too recommend not using just a number as an ID, it is allowed in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex value, like all CSS values, needs to be a string.

```
div.style.backgroundColor = '#3e4046';
```

If you supply a none-string value to a CSS property, it will be cast to a string. For example, `0x3e4046` when cast to a string equals `'4079686'`, which is not a valid CSS color. In the case of `#3e4046`, you actually have a syntax error, since `#3e4046` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: `div.style.lineHeight = 2` works fine. So to be pedantic about the matter, setting a style property to a number is not a problem in and of itself, but the value must be acceptable for that property. So it's not a matter of "all CSS values...need to be a string" (although internally they will end up being strings). In this case the problem is specifically that `backgroundColor' does not take a numeric value.

Comment: @torazaburo A fair point, although technically that only works because `2` will be auto-magically cast to the string `'2'`. I'll make a note of this.